# Displaying small responsive images with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a small social network king of thing and I'm struggling to display the user's profile pic along with his/her posts.

This is what I have now:

[image]

The problem is the profile's pic on the left side. First off, the "Xmas sucks..." text has been pushed down by the image (I suspect this requires the *clearfix* class to be fixed - problem is I couldn't get it working). Secondly, if the screen size changes, the image overflows (I think that's the term) the column width:

[image]

You can see above (IPhone 6 Plus) that the "@grinch..." line has been pushed down.

That's my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'+':true">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading line-break" ng-if="post.title">
          <strong>{{post.title}}</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body line-break">
          <div class="row small-gap-row-below">
            <div class="col-md-1">
              <img src='http://localhost:50003/image/{{user.profilePicKey}}'
                   alt="Profile Picture" class="img-responsive img-rounded"
                   style="max-height: 50px; max-width: 50px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <span><strong>@{{post.username}}</strong></span>
                <small class="pull-right">18-May-2016 - 16:02</small>
              <hr class="small-margin-top"></hr>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-11">
              <p froala-view="post.content"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I'm using the *img-responsive* class, shouldn't the image be automatically resized to fit the parent? In which case, it shouldn't overflow?

I'm setting *style="max-height: 50px; max-width: 50px;"* because otherwise  the displayed image is very small. As it says 'max-*' I'm supposing this shouldn't break responsiveness because it still is a "flexible" measure.

I suspect it's not rocket science to get this working but as I'm not experience with CSS/Bootstrap/Frontend-in-general I'm having a hard time.

**UPDATE:**

I've changed col-md-* to col-xs as suggested but it didn't work:

[image]

The username was placed on top of the image.

**UPDATE II**

Img CSS:

```
element.style {
    max-height: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;
}
.img-rounded {
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .img-responsive, .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%; (not applied!)
    height: auto;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; (not applied!)
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; (not applied!)
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Inherited from body.ng-scope
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
Inherited from html
html {
    font-size: 10px; (not applied!)
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif; (not applied!)
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; (not applied!)
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
Pseudo ::before element
:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; (not applied!)
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; (not applied!)
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; (not applied!)
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; (not applied!)
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**UPDATE III**

Using col-xs-* along with col-sm-* as suggested:

[image]

A gap between the profile pic and the username (@grinch) appeared. Also the post content has been pushed to the left.

Comment: What is the css of the img?  It looks like it's got absolute positioning in it?

Comment: I have included the css in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to this instead, so that it doesn't collapse.  Putting col-md-xx means it will break to 100% width for small devices.

```
           <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1">
              <img src='http://localhost:50003/image/{{user.profilePicKey}}'
                   alt="Profile Picture" class="img-responsive img-rounded"
                   style="max-height: 50px; max-width: 50px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-11">
                <span><strong>@{{post.username}}</strong></span>
                <small class="pull-right">18-May-2016 - 16:02</small>
              <hr class="small-margin-top"></hr>
            </div>
```

Comment: Came really close! The image doens't overflow anymore but a gap between the image and the "@grinch..." appeared. Also, the post content has been pushed to the left.

Comment: Just posted a printscreen

Comment: try using xs-2 and xs-10.  Otherwise, what you want is to use just img float:left when media is less than xx px. in a media query for this particular image, and basically forget about using bootstrap colums for that row.  that would involve adding a custom class and writing some css.  This may vary depending on how you want to go about it.

Comment: Alright - I'll need to have a look at how to use media queries first because I've never worked with them before. Meanwhile I'll use your solution because it's already enough for the time being :) I accepted your answer - thanks for your help, Howard.

Comment: Good luck... I think changing the columns to xs-2 and xs-10 should make it fit.  Without being able to inspect element, it's just a visual guess at this point. ;)